# Placing an image on another which is stretched in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, view

I have a UI in which I have once image as background and Hence it stretches itself to fill the screen. I want to place another image at a particular position w.r.t. original image. How do I do that?

To elaborate more,say I have an image of 320x320 which is at background, and has a white square of 20x20 in it at (50,50)(left top corner) . I have another image of 20x20 which should fill it in. Now when the background stretches, I  want  this image to stretch & place accordingly so as to fit in that white box itself.

e.g. lets say I've following bckgrnd images with 2 yellow boxes. Now the foregroud image is to be placed exactly in upper yellow box. Since the background image expands/shrinks (that too differently along x and y), the foreground should also **stretch and position** itself to fit the yellow box.

Background Image: http://oi52.tinypic.com/2yn5nut.jpg

Foreground Image: http://i52.tinypic.com/dm3503.png

This is my xml file as of now. Pt.(32,47) is the top left corner of top yellow box in background img

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/bkgrnd">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/foregrnd"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" android:layout_marginTop="42px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="37px">
    </ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: and it gives output as

Horizontal: http://i52.tinypic.com/50ftkw.png

Vertical: http://i52.tinypic.com/2ikxuab.png

Now I want the forground image to scale and position itself to fit in the top yellow box

Answer (score 0):

please tell me about what layout are you using???

according to my understanding i think u have 2 images and u want one as background image and other image as your foreground image.
For this you can use the relative layout and set its height and width as "fill_parant"
and set your first image as the background of relative layout. using android:background = "firstimage"

and then place the other image view where ever you want.

Comment: I am using linear layout. Have added images to explain the problem exactly

Comment: @ajain: for exact placement of any widget u need to go with the relative layout. place yr second image view on the upper yellow box by giving margins from top and left and get the set property fitxy = true

Comment: How do i know the margins from the top and left, as bckgrnd image might have changed its scale according to screen size

Comment: and it gives output as 
Horizontal: i52.tinypic.com/50ftkw.png 
Vertical: i52.tinypic.com/2ikxuab.png 
Now I want the forground image to scale and position itself to fit in the top yellow box